# spring boot with spring security : Error creating bean with name 'filterChain'

Tags: spring, spring-security

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'filterChain' defined in class path resource [com/udacity/jdnd/course3/critter/security/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'filterChain' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.HttpSecurityConfiguration.httpSecurity'

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'filterChain' defined in class path resource [com/udacity/jdnd/course3/critter/security/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'filterChain' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.HttpSecurityConfiguration.httpSecurity'
```

Comment: Could share the `WebSecurityConfiguration` class? Also, version of spring security?

Comment: https://github.com/wongkevinmanuel/P3-CritterChronologer/blob/master/src/main/java/com/udacity/jdnd/course3/critter/security/WebSecurityConfiguration.java

Version spring security:
spring-security-config = 5.7.2
spring-boot-starter-security = 2.7.5